# How to inject data into chartjs plugin function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, chart.js

I have the following chart with plugin function:

```
this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {

  type: 'doughnut',
  plugins: {
    beforeDraw: function (chart) {
      //I want to use data here
    }
});
```

Data from a provider:

```
  constructor(public dataService: Data)
```

And data is easily accessible from the class where chart and plugin is located, but I dont know how to inject it inside of plugin function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, everything is in the 'chart' parameter just deep inside:

```
chart.config.config.data.someData;
```